Block access to files without login - CodeIgniter 3 Nginx
I migrated a CodeIgniter 3 application from an Apache server to Nginx. For logged in users, it should be possible to download some PDF files. I need to block access to these folders directly. For example: example.com.br/files/xyz.pdf. If I access the browser without logging in, I can access these files. If I put:
location /(versoes|lgpd)/ {
 deny all;
 return 403;
}

It doesn't work. Access remains available.
Question: I need to block external access, however, allow logged in users to be able to download.

If by "/(versoes|lgpd)/" you mean regex catching "versoes" or "lgpd" - so your url is either
example.com.br/versoes/
or
example.com.br/lgpd/
Then you should add "~" as an indicator that what follows should be treated as regex (unless your URL is example.com.br/(versoes|lgpd)/, literally).
Also - it's a good practice to add "^" to indicate the start of the url (again - assuming you mean regex).
So - my config would look like this:
location ~ ^/(versoes|lgpd)/ {
 deny all;
 return 403;
}

Let me also note, that you can (and probably should) think about file permissions.
Example: if your nginx is running as nginx:nginx changing owner of versoes and lgpd directories to, lets say: root, will also prevent external access (because nginx can't read them by default).

Yes, it's a regex. The application is in CodeIgniter Framework. When I do this, I cannot access the files when I'm logged in the app. I already changed the permissions to www-data and to root.

@Zanellato I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter. If you're logged in then from the nginx point of view you can check headers and make a decision based on those. Example: location (...) { if ($remote_addr != [valid IP of logged in user]) {  deny all;  return 403; } }.
Just a crude example. You can choose whatever header your logged in users provide, I'd reuse $cookie_[some-name] if available.
